# react-native requestanimationframe - flicker - freeze - app crash

Tags: react-native, requestanimationframe

am learning to build app using react-native and below is the component code that am using. The problem is - when I simulate this app - it crashes in few seconds. I couldnt understand what is causing this problem. Can someone please suggest.
I am trying to animate a canvas circle using requestAnimationFrame in this component.

Thank you ..

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
import Canvas from 'react-native-canvas';

export default class ThreeDiscs extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            context: null,
            screen: {
                width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                height: Dimensions.get('window').height
            },
            a: 0,
            b: 0,
            c: 100,
            d: 100
        };
        this.coordinates = {
            a: 0,
            b: 0,
            c: 100,
            d: 100
        };
        this.directions = {
            increment: 5,
            direction: 0
        };
        this.discs = [
            { 
               x: 150,
               y: 250,
               lastX: 150,
               lastY: 250,
               velocityX: -3.2,
               velocityY: 3.5,
               radius: 10,
               innerColor: 'rgba(255,255,0,1)',
               middleColor: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.7)',
               outerColor: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.5)',
               strokeStyle: 'gray',
            }
         ];
         this.numDiscs = this.discs.length;
    }

    rendercanvas = (canvas) => {
        canvas.width = this.state.screen.width;
        canvas.height = this.state.screen.height;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.setState({context: context});
        context.fillStyle = 'purple';
        context.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
        this.drawBackground(context);
        this.update(context);
        this.draw(context);
        this.animatecanvas(context);
    }

   drawBackground(context) {
     var STEP_Y = 12,
         i = this.state.screen.height;

     context.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
     context.lineWidth = 0.5;

     while(i > STEP_Y*4) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, i);
        context.lineTo(context.canvas.width, i);
        context.stroke();
        i -= STEP_Y;
     }

     context.save();

     context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(100,0,0,0.3)';
     context.lineWidth = 1;

     context.beginPath();

     context.moveTo(35,0);
     context.lineTo(35,context.canvas.height);
     context.stroke();

     context.restore();
  }

   update(context) {
     var disc = null;

     for(var i=0; i < this.numDiscs; ++i) {
        disc = this.discs[i];

        if (disc.x + disc.velocityX + disc.radius > context.canvas.width ||
            disc.x + disc.velocityX - disc.radius < 0) 
           disc.velocityX = -disc.velocityX;

        if (disc.y + disc.velocityY + disc.radius > context.canvas.height ||
            disc.y + disc.velocityY - disc.radius  < 0) 
           disc.velocityY= -disc.velocityY;

        disc.x += disc.velocityX;
        disc.y += disc.velocityY;
     }
  }

   draw(context) {
     var disc = this.discs[i];

     for(var i=0; i < this.numDiscs; ++i) {
        disc = this.discs[i];
        context.save();
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(disc.x, disc.y, disc.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.strokeStyle = disc.strokeStyle;
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();
        context.restore();
     }
  }

  animatecanvas(context){
    context.clearRect(0,0,this.state.screen.width,this.state.screen.height);
    this.drawBackground(context);
    this.update(context);
    this.draw(context);

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {this.animatecanvas(context)});
  }
    render(){
        return(
            <Canvas ref={this.rendercanvas} />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really write a more clear question, what is your code, what have you tried to fix it etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I am using requestAnimationFrame to animate a circle in React-Native project. After running the simulator, the circle moves for sometime and app is crashing in almost a minute.